# calculate rank in highscore from 2 tables

Tags: sql, mysql, ranking, rank

i have a trivia game and i want to reward users for 2 events:
1) answering correctly
2) sending a question to the questions pool

i want to query for score and rank of a specific player and i use this query:

```
SELECT (correct*10+sent*30) AS score, @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank 
FROM   (  trivia_players 
          JOIN (  SELECT COUNT(*) AS sent, senderid 
                  FROM trivia_questions 
                  WHERE senderid='$userid'
               ) a 
          ON trivia_players.userid=a.senderid
       )  
       ORDER BY score DESC
```

and it works if the player is in both tables i.e answered correctly AND sent a question.
but it doesn't work if a player hasn't sent a question

any idea how to fix this query? ($userid is the given parameter)

thanks!

Thanks Tom! only problem is the ranks are not correct:
 userid          score   rank
  58217  380  1
  12354          80  3
 32324           0  2

Comment: Table definitions would be a big help here.

Comment: trivia_players columns: userid,user,last,correct,total

Comment: trivia_questions columns: id,question,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4,correct_answer,sender,senderid

Comment: You might want to use the code formatting button when you put SQL in your queries in the future.  It makes it a little easier to read than just plain text.  I went ahead and formatted it as best I could, feel free to change it however you see fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do it like this:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    score,
    rank
FROM
(
    SELECT
        TP.user_id,
        (TP.correct * 10) + (COUNT(TQ.sender_id) * 30) AS score,
        @rank:=@rank + 1 AS rank
    FROM
        Trivia_Players TP
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Trivia_Questions TQ ON
        TQ.sender_id = TP.user_id
    GROUP BY
        TP.user_id,
        TP.correct
    ORDER BY
        score DESC
) AS SQ
WHERE
    SQ.user_id = $user_id
```

I don't use MySQL much, so the syntax may not be perfect. I think that you can use a subquery like this in MySQL. Assuming that MySQL handles COUNT() by only counting rows with a non-null value for , this should work.

The keys are that you do a COUNT over a non-null column from Trivia Questions so that it counts them up by the user and you need to use a subquery so that you can get ranks for everyone BEFORE constraining to a particular user id.

Comment: Shouldn't it be a left outer join from Trivia_Players to Trivia_Questions?

Comment: Thanks... I have no idea why I put RIGHT since I almost never actually use RIGHT JOINs. Correcting it now.

Comment: thanks it almost worked, i updated the question with your answer (still needs some tweaking)

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected outcome for a case where it doesn't work? I put together a simple test and it worked on that, although it could simply be a case of my data being too simplistic.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a **RIGHT JOIN** or **LEFT JOIN**? Just off the top of my head!